# HTML - Can't identify reason behind gap above div

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to build a simple landing page but I'm encountering what I think is a simple oversight on my part but I can't seem to point out where I'm going wrong.

As seen in the image below my problem is the gap above the blue navigation bar which shouldn't be there. As you will see in the CSS code below I have no margin on the class main_div.

[image]

Any ideas as to why the white gap at the top is there?

Here's my HTML (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
       <meta charset='utf-8'>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/public.css">

       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/utilities/utilities.js&2.6.0/build/container/container_core-min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/carousel.js"></script>

       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css&2.6.0/build/base/base-min.css">

       <link href="stylesheets/carouseltwo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="stylesheets/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

       <title>Welcome</title>

    </head>

<body>

    <!-- Main div after topbar div -->
    <div class="main_div">

        <div id="topbar">
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>HOW IT WORKS</span></a></li>
               <li ><a href='#'><span>LOG IN</span></a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>

        <!-- Welcome message -->
        <div class="welcome_message">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>

        <!-- Header Carousel -->
        <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');">

                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Caption A</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');">

                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Caption B</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');">

                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

    </div>      
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my CSS (public.css):

```
    html {height: 100%; width: 100%;}

body {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0;
    font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif;    
    font-size: 14px; 
    line-height: 15px;
}

/* Main div - this will hold all the componenets*/
.main_div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
}

/* Top bar*/
#topbar {
  background: #3399CC;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px #808080;
  float: left;
}

/* Logo img button*/
#topbar img {
    position: relative;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    float: left;
}

/* ul */
#topbar ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
}

/* li */
#topbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Insert a gap after every <ul> element */
#topbar ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* a */
#topbar ul li a {
  font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;  
}

#topbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

/* bullet point after the menu name */
#topbar ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: .5;
}

#topbar ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #00FF00;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}

#topbar ul li.last > a:after,
#topbar ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}

#topbar ul li.active a {
  color: #FFDD00;
}

#topbar ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#topbar.align-right li.last > a:after,
#topbar.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}

#topbar.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}

/*Overall/Super div*/
.main_div {
  width: 100%;  
  float: left;
  font-family: "DINPro-Bold",Georgia,Serif; 
}

/* Welcome message div*/
.welcome_message {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;  
  float: left;
  color: #999999;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFCC00;
}
```

Here's my 2nd CSS file (modern-business.css):

```
/* Global Styles */

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

.img-portfolio {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.img-hover:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Home Page Carousel */

header.carousel {
    height: 50%;
}

header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* 404 Page Styles */

.error-404 {
    font-size: 100px;
}

/* Pricing Page Styles */

.price {
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.price sup {
    top: -20px;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.period {
    display: block;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Footer Styles */

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}

/* Responsive Styles */

@media(max-width:991px) {
    .customer-img,
    .img-related {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    .img-portfolio {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    header.carousel .carousel {
        height: 70%;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: I've added the modern-business.css file

Thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine dude http://jsfiddle.net/ntzxydhk/

Comment: Hm, it doesn't show in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jh2def88/ Is there more CSS?

Comment: Why don't you just debug it with Inspect Element feature in your browser?

Comment: Why do you use position:relative so much?? I don't think you need it. And why width/height 100%?? That's the default anyway.

Comment: css working fine ,I think that css you are linking may be creating issue.Debug it with Inspect Element feature in your browser

Comment: the code provided works fine, so maybe it's in the other style sheets or JavaScript related

Comment: Is this a WordPress website?

Comment: @Tambo: I've also had a look at the code on jsfiddle .. And there's no gap .. may be something in modern-business.css might be the problem .. i've edit my OP and added it ..

Comment: @Sleek Geek: This isn't a word press website although I'm using a bootstrap template as a guide with regards to its design.

Comment: @everyone: thanks for the suggestions including the inspect element .. it all helped ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine in your fiddle because modern-business.css isn't included in the fiddle

however it contains:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}
```

Which is probably the reason for your problem, remove that or set

```
body{padding:0px !important}
```

in your own stylesheet.

Comment: nice one .. your suggestion worked like a charm ... indeed it is because of the padding-top in modern-business.css